# Word-Scripting: replace nonbreaking spaces with thin spaces?

Tags: vba, ms-word

I use word to open (special) html documents for printing and want to write a script to fix a small issue:

In the html file I have numbers like '15 cm' written as '15 cm', so there will be no line break between the number '15' and the unit 'cm'.

My problem is: The spacing is too wide, especially when word expands the spaces to fit a sentence to the margins.

So I'd like to replace these   with some kind of thin spaces using a word VBA script. I guess I need to enumerate the paragraphs, but I'm not sure how to replace text in there. This is what I came up with so far, but I don't know how to write the html nbsp in word and what to use for thin spaces, maybe someone can help me here?

```
Sub MakeThinSpaces()
Dim para As Paragraph
For Each para In ActiveDocument.Paragraphs
  replace the &nbsp; with some &thinsp; here?
Next
End Sub
```

Comment: A THIN SPACE is by definition a breakable space, so you might actually make things worse.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Thin space is Unicode 8201. (A narrow no-break space would be 8239).
It should work with this code using the selection object.
`^s` is the wildcard for a protected space, you could also use `Chr(160)`

```
Selection.WholeStory
With Selection.Find
    .Text = "^s"
    .Replacement.Text = ChrW(8201)
    .MatchWildcards = True
End With
Selection.Find.Execute Replace:=wdReplaceAll
```

Comment: This looks perfect! Does it only work on the selected text? Or does 'Selection.WholeStory' select the full text?

Comment: Documents are structured somehow into 'sections' and 'stories', I'm not all into the depths of that. But here yes, the main document body is one 'story' and that method selects it all (would not include headers/footers and such special areas).

Comment: Great! And my word does neither break the 8201 nor the 8239, it does not seem to differ between these two.

Answer (score 0):

Regarding replacement in the entire text, there is an alternative solution to selecting the whole story.

E.g. following code would replace all non-breaking spaces in the document with normal spaces:

```
With ActiveDocument.Content.Find
    .Execute "^s", replacewith:=" ", Replace:=wdReplaceAll
End With
```

The wildcard-match parameter, should it really be required, could be packet into the .Execute statement in the same way.